# Avoiding stray pointers in if conditions involving AND

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

How does these two if condition evaluate in the case of avoiding stray pointers?

```
if (vShop[0].vItem[vShop[0].itsActiveItem]!=NULL && vShop[0].vItem[vShop[0].itsActiveItem]->itsQuantity>0) DoPurchase();
```

where vShop[0] is a vector of objects and vItem is a vector of pointers to objects.

I want to make sure that the pointer does not evaluate NULL **before** it further checks  vShop[0].vItem[vShop[0].itsActiveItem]->itsQuantity>0.

Or should I have to do it separately, that is:

```
if (vShop[0].vItem[vShop[0].itsActiveItem]!=NULL) if (vShop[0].vItem[vShop[0].itsActiveItem]->itsQuantity>0) DoPurchase();
```

In other words does the first case is a sequential check and if the first condition evaluates, the second condition is automatically dropped? Many thanks.

Comment: Using `if (ptr != NULL && ptr->something == x)` is perfectly acceptable.  If it gets to be a long string of such expressions I prefer to break it down into separate lines, however.

Comment: Its called short circuiting if you want to get more information on it. Likewise `if( x || y )` does not evaluate `y` if `x` is true.

Comment: It's not just acceptable, it is the standard idiom for ensuring that a test doesn't go through a null pointer. If the expression gets too long, it's probably a sign that the Rule of Demeter is being broken.

Comment: Is the second case"out of standard"? I have used the second expression so far and wonder if it would be wise to go through the whole program and change in to the first case. Item is also instantiated within Shop, so I hope this doesn't break any rules...

Comment: If you're putting both `if` statements on the same line, that's probably not a good idea, since it's easy for an experienced (and "maze bright") programmer to skim past the embedded `if` without noticing it, and, when he does notice it, he'll have to back up and spend several seconds figuring out what it's doing, since it's not standard practice.  (In fact, it's rarely a good idea to have `if (boolExpression)` without `{` following, even if what follows is only one statement.)

Comment: good to know about these practices - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the former, since `&&` only evaluates the second condition if the first one was `true`. Hence code like

```
if ( p != NULL && p->age == 42 )
```

is perfectly valid.

Beward that this is only true if you are dealing with built-in types, the same assumption is no longer true when `&&` is overloaded for UDTs, but for plain pointers, the above is fine and it is exactly what you need.

Comment: Actually, that's not OK, unless the type of "foo" has the operator `==` defined to compare to a character string.

Comment: @HotLicks I improved the answer anyways to avoid confusion and distraction of the real topic at hand.

Comment: @user2856452 I'm not sure you understood the unrelated confusion about `==` correctly, so I improved the answer. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: So this does not apply to my case of having a simple pointers to objects, right? Edit: I know about the assignment operator, so I got confused if there is something like a "==" operator for objects that I would have to take care of.

Comment: @user2856452 No it doesn't, your case is fine.

Comment: @user2856452 - Yeah, it's fine, other than the fact that the C++ expression `someValue == someString` is almost always wrong.